# Output array of hashes from Ruby on Rails to chart.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, chart.js, chart.js2

I'm having some trouble preparing data from my **Ruby on Rails** project for use in **chart.js**, when using time as a second axis.

I've looked at various other questions and managed to get very close, but am having issues with exporting the data in a format that chart.js can recognise.

Thanks for your help!

---

## Issue

I need the data to be printed in this form:

```
data: [
  {"x":1567006282000,"y":145},        
  {"x":1567009767000,"y":120},
  {"x":1567009838000,"y":130}
]
```

But am currently getting the following:

```
data: [
    {&quot;x&quot;:1567006282000,&quot;y&quot;:145}, 
    {&quot;x&quot;:1567009767000,&quot;y&quot;:120}, 
    {&quot;x&quot;:1567009838000,&quot;y&quot;:130}
]
```

---

## Current Attempt

I am creating the array as follows from within my controller, where `reading_time` and `obs.heart_rate` are integers, I *think* this is creating an array of hashes:

```
...
@hr.push ( { :x => reading_time, :y => obs.heart_rate  } )
...
```

I then print this in my view, converting to json so that it would in theory work with the javascript library chart.js:

```
...
data: <%= @hr.to_json %>,
...
```

Pretty sure my issue is somewhere in the two lines above, but the full code is below in case it is needed.

---

## Full Code

This is how I am creating (what I think) is an array of hashes within my **controller**:

```
def chart 

    # Load observations for specific patient
    @observations = Observation.where(:patient_id => params[:patient_id]);

    # Prep arrays
    @readings = []
    @hr = []

    # Cycle through all observations for this patient
    @observations.each do |obs| 

        # Convert created time to integer
        # Multiple by 1000 as chart.js expects milliseconds while ruby uses seconds from UNIX epoch
        reading_time = obs.created_at.to_i * 1000

        # Add time to array so we can use this for the labels
        @readings.push(reading_time)

        # Create hash of time and observation value
        hr_temp = {:x => reading_time , :y => obs.heart_rate }

        # Push hash to the array
        @hr.push( hr_temp )

        # Repeat for other obserations - blood pressure, oxygen sats, etc

    end

end
```

And finally how I am then printing that within my **view**:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha256-xKeoJ50pzbUGkpQxDYHD7o7hxe0LaOGeguUidbq6vis=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<script>

var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var scatterChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: <%= @readings %>,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Heart Rate',
            data: <%= @hr.to_json %>,
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                type: 'time',
                time: {
                    parser: 'X', // parse x values as unix timestamp
                    tooltipFormat: 'MMM Do, \'YY'
                },
            }]
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

---

## Working Example

This is a working hard coded example showing what I am aiming for.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var scatterChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Heart Rate',
            data: [
              {"x":1567006282000,"y":145},        
              {"x":1567009767000,"y":120},
              {"x":1567009838000,"y":130}
            ]
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
  xAxes: [{
   type: 'time',
   time: {
    parser: 'X', // parse x values as unix timestamp
    tooltipFormat: 'MMM Do, \'YY'
   },
  }]
 }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha256-xKeoJ50pzbUGkpQxDYHD7o7hxe0LaOGeguUidbq6vis=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: from ruby prespective, if you have the data in hash object, when not to use [`to_json`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#module-JSON-label-Generating+JSON)?

Comment: Try `data: <%= @hr.to_json.html_safe %>`

Comment: Thanks, .html_safe was the answer. Appreciate the help! That took me hours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to rendering, which uses `to_s` under the hood which could cause some encoding issues while rendering from a `string` type object. You should try using using `html_safe` method on the object returned by `@hr.to_json` like `@hr.to_json.html_safe`

Comment: Thanks, `.html_safe` was the answer. Appreciate the help! That took me hours

Comment: @OliverTrampleasure No problem :D